# Add a static file (such as an executable) to a project

Tags: gitlab

I am working on a Gitlab project and we are trying to figure out the best way to store static files that we do not want tracked by git. The primary reason that we don't want these files tracked is that the repo size would grow really fast. There are two primary examples...

1) The project is itself generating large executables. We want to have a place where we can save specific versions of the executables without having them tracked by git.

2) To build the project, we need a lot of input files. These are necessary for the build process, but change fairly frequently (for example if we were doing image processing, these might be a high set of images). For us, these files only amount to about 20MB, but they change weekly. So if we tracked these changes, our repo would grow at an untenable pace.

Is there a place in the Gitlab interface where we can store files like I mention above? Or how should we handle this problem. The solution so far has been to share such files over Slack/email. But that is difficult to maintain with newcomers to the project.

Answer (score 0):

1) for this there are `artifacts` in Gitlab CI. These can be downloaded after a CI cycle. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html

2) no there is not a functionality to store static files for the build process. But the best way would be to create a file share e.g. NFS on a remote server, mount this share, as read only for security reasons, at boot on the CI server and then bind this directory during the CI job to a internal directory in the docker container. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#volumes-in-the-runnersdocker-section